# Sending websocket data to arbitrary client (based on e.g. username)

Tags: websocket

Is the following possible with websockets:

- UserA and UserB are users of a site.
- UserA logs in to the site and starts up a websocket connection.
- UserB has a message for UserA, so they submit a form that is handled by some script on the server (doesn't matter if it's through WS, XHR or just a plain form)
- The server sends the message to UserA through their websocket connection - without the server code just checking the database continually for new messages.

Ideally the script that handles the sending of the message would do everything - put the message into the database and send it to the recipient's websocket connection as well.

Edit: here is the actual scenario I have in mind for this kind of functionality:

I am developing a chess site which currently uses long-polling for updating the user when their opponent moves, and a few other things like a chat box beneath the board.

Here's the PHP script that the user calls to make a move, with code added (near the end) to illustrate what I want to do:

/xhr/move.php

```
<?php
require_once "base.php";
require_once "Data.php";
require_once "php/livechess/LiveGame.php";
require_once "php/init.php";

$result=false;

if($session->user->signedin()) {
    $q=Data::unserialise($_GET["q"]);

    if(isset($q["gid"]) && isset($q["fs"]) && isset($q["ts"])) {
        $colour=Db::cell("
            select colour from seats
            where user='{$session->user->username}'
            and gid='{$q["gid"]}'
            and type='".SEAT_TYPE_PLAYER."'
        ");

        if($colour!==false) {
            $promote_to=QUEEN;

            if(isset($q["promote_to"])) {
                $promote_to=$q["promote_to"];
            }

            $game=new LiveGame($q["gid"]);

            if($game->position->active===$colour) {
                if($game->move($q["fs"], $q["ts"], $promote_to)->success) {
                    $result=$game->history->main_line->last_move->mtime;
                    $game->check_premoves();
                    $game->save();

                    /*
                    here is where the functionality I'm talking to would come in:

                    (some pseudocode for brevity)
                    */

                    $opponent_username=Db::cell("select user from seats where colour=".opp_colour($colour)." and etc");

                    send_websocket_data($opponent_username, Data::serialise($game->history->main_line->last_move));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

echo Data::serialise($result);
?>
```

I have no idea what the implementation of the send_websocket_data function would be like, except that it would take a username and some data to send.

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time, money and programmer resources.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: I kind of left it bare-bones as I wasn't sure if there was something fundamental to websockets that I had misunderstood I'll edit the question to add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes websocket installs a full-duplex connection with the connected clients. So the server can send messages to them anytime.

Then the implementation depends on your client and server.

As you seem to like php, you could look into [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). I did not try it though.

You could also read about [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Also keep in mind that websockets won't work everywhere, depending on the network - proxies mostly. So you may have to handle graceful degradation to long-polling for example. That's what async frameworks offer but in other languages (atmosphere/java, Socket.oi/node.js)

Websockets are cool! Goog luck :)

Comment: Thanks, looked into Ratchet and the answer is in the docs under Connections.  I knew the server could send messages whenever, but I was still thinking in terms of having one running instance of the server code for each connection, like standard HTTP, with no obvious way for communication between connections.  What I needed to understand was that your code deals with the opening and closing of connections as well, and (with Ratchet at least) there is one instance of the server code for the whole server.